# PHP Post group of repeated inputs

Tags: php, forms, post, submit

I have a form for a Company model. A Company has one or more Contacts in my model so in my form I have inputs for client_name, client_phone, client_email and I can repeat them with a little javascript I made so I can add as many clients as I want. I need to post this and get those objects grouped in order to be able to foreach 'em, I mean something like that:

```
client: [
    {name: "Alan", phone: "123456123", email: "alan@example.com},
    {name: "Alan", phone: "123456123", email: "alan@example.com},
    {name: "Alan", phone: "123456123", email: "alan@example.com}
]
```

How should name the inputs to get this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm reading your question correctly, you can do something like this:

```
<form method="post">
    <input name="client[0][name]" value="Alan">
    <input name="client[0][phone]" value="123456123">
    <input name="client[0][email]" value="alan@example.com">
    <input name="client[1][name]" value="Alan">
    <input name="client[1][phone]" value="123456123">
    <input name="client[1][email]" value="alan@example.com">
    <input name="client[2][name]" value="Alan">
    <input name="client[2][phone]" value="123456123">
    <input name="client[2][email]" value="alan@example.com">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

which will give an array in this format, ready for `json_encode`ing:

```
Array
(
    [client] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Alan
                    [phone] => 123456123
                    [email] => alan@example.com
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Alan
                    [phone] => 123456123
                    [email] => alan@example.com
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Alan
                    [phone] => 123456123
                    [email] => alan@example.com
                )

        )

)
```

Another option ref comment:

```
<form method="post">
    <input name="name[]" value="Alan">
    <input name="phone[]" value="123456123">
    <input name="email[]" value="alan@example.com">
    <input name="name[]" value="Alan">
    <input name="phone[]" value="123456123">
    <input name="email[]" value="alan@example.com">
    <input name="name[]" value="Alan">
    <input name="phone[]" value="123456123">
    <input name="email[]" value="alan@example.com">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

And the PHP to rebuild the array:

```
$array = array();
foreach ($_POST['name'] as $key => $name) {
    $array[] = array(
        'name' => $name,
        'phone' => $_POST['phone'][$key],
        'email' => $_POST['email'][$key]
    );
}
```

Comment: I wanted something even more automatic, because the number of times i'll have these fields depends on how many repeaters I add. But I think I'll have to take this option. Thanks!

Comment: There's another option where you don't have to use the numbers, I'll add it in a sec